# Element Reference in Material Components only return _animationMode property

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the properties of my HTML Element which is apparently `<mat-card>` tag using Angular's Element Referencing and accessing it through `@ViewChild`; however, I was not able to get all the properties of that element and only returned with an `object` that has `_animationMode` property only.

Here's the [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5czcgm) in order for you to replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewChildren as mat-card does not have **nativeElement**..

```
  @ViewChildren('customForm', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) customForm: any;
```

which gives you list of nativeElements.
Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7nfau.

Hope this helps.